# What's the single point listed in a GPS track's attribute table?

Tags: qgis

When I import GPS waypoints to QGIS, it includes coordinates that show up in the attribute table. That's great. What I don't understand is when I import tracks. I still get coordinates, as though it is a single point. What point is it? Is the numerical data available for the whole track?
Thanks
TVZ

Comment: Please add which how you imported the GPS data (which tools? which source?)

Comment: (Note: These tracks have been added by a variety of means over time, from Garmin GPS units, mostly using the DNR Garmin interface.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GPS data the protocol is points that are read as from and to sequentialy and have time, so is read out as a time string and drawn based on the points time. So no real vector but a gps program will create a vector. If you want to work with the data you might want  to convert to gpx and import to a gis with a shape conversion, or idealy import the live dat out put straight into a shape file through a arcgis extension such as DNR Garmin http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html.
You could try using traces instead of tracks, typicaly gps data is visualized in gis as a bread crumb trail "points" due to the problems of getting a shape conversion and live importing. Other usefull tools are trackmaker, cetus gps, and gpsbabel.

Comment: Thanks Lewis. I think this is a little beyond me, so I guess I won't worry about it right now.